# Error on launcher and using AnimateDiff extension

Tags: python

Since I tried animateDiff I'm getting an error of script pa.py each time I launch stable diffusion. I deleted venv folder a few times with no luck. I also deleted AnimateDiff folder and install it again.

Here is the message I can see on the panel:

```
*** Error loading script: pa.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\scripts.py", line 527, in load_scripts
        script_module = script_loading.load_module(scriptfile.path)
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\script_loading.py", line 10, in load_module
        module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\scripts\pa.py", line 1, in <module>
```

After that I can see a very long {"payload":{ line code.

This is the error I get when I try to animate something:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\call_queue.py", line 57, in f
        res = list(func(*args, **kwargs))
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\call_queue.py", line 36, in f
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\txt2img.py", line 110, in txt2img
        processed = processing.process_images(p)
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\processing.py", line 785, in process_images
        res = process_images_inner(p)
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\processing.py", line 933, in process_images_inner
        x_samples_ddim = decode_latent_batch(p.sd_model, samples_ddim, target_device=devices.cpu, check_for_nans=True)
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\processing.py", line 653, in decode_latent_batch
        raise e
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\processing.py", line 637, in decode_latent_batch
        devices.test_for_nans(sample, "vae")
      File "F:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\devices.py", line 255, in test_for_nans
        raise NansException(message)
    modules.devices.NansException: A tensor with all NaNs was produced in VAE. This could be because there's not enough precision to represent the picture. Try adding --no-half-vae commandline argument to fix this. Use --disable-nan-check commandline argument to disable this check.
```

I'm using Python 3.10.6

It's my first time writting an error, so please let me know if I can add more info about it.

Delete folder Venv and delete AnimateDiff folder

Reload launcher and reinstall AnimateDiff extension

Fix the error on the launcher and being able to use extension

Comment: So I tried to fix it by deleting all stable diffusion folder and reinstalling it again using python and somehow it works. I guess upgrading and downgrading python and so made a few false routes and that's why I was getting errors.